# Rerunning a Job From Child Job in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, jobs

I have this Job Setup

```
<batch:job id="job1">
    <batch:step id="step1"  allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <batch:job ref="job2">
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<batch:job id="job2">
    <batch:step id="Step2" allow-start-if-complete="true">
         <batch:next on="Fail" to="failstep"></batch:next>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="failstep"   allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <batch:job ref="job1">
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

On executing this the startup itself throws an error

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilderException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: A Step must have a name

Any help is appreciated on this

Comment: is that missing `>` on the second step just a typo?

Comment: That is just a type my orginal job has lot more steps. i quickly put together a trimmed version for the question.. Please ignore that typo.. other than that the concept is same.

Comment: without complete configuration and stacktrace it is hard to help, in your posted configuration it looks like a circular reference between job1 and job2, looks strange to me

Comment: Why is it strange ?.. like you are running a job and that initiates another job. In my case it picks up a set of transactions to settle and sent to a party and then waits for response. Once it gets response it again checks if there are more transactions if so call the first job again. So first part is job 1 and second part is job 2. why they are separate jobs is because i can restart the jobs easily.. there are chances that the partner might sent a wrong file and that will cause the job to complete and makes it tedious to restart..

Comment: In Nutshell it is better to have seperate jobs so that it is easy to restart and that i need to run the first job from second job if there are more transactions..

Answer (score 1):

I got this error. when I had the  step ID and other bean ID are the same . so after I changed the name of the step the error gone. Just check if you have some IDs are same in your XML file .I wish that can help.

Comment: Perfect. I had named my batch:step id the same as my referencing bean id. Thank you for sharing your suggestion.